# Bootstrap Navbar toggle button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I shrink the window and click the button it doesn't respond. How do I fix this?

```
<button type="button" 
        class="navbar-toggle" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target=".navbar-collapse">

    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Page 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Libraries are jQuery 2.1.3 and bootstrap 3.3.1.

Comment: are you including the Bootstrap javascript file?  Also make sure it's included at the bottom of your page.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: can we see the html that includes the js files in your html?

Comment: I have these included, are they enough?

Comment: it's not enough to include the scripts, the *have* to be at the bottom of your page for the toggle to work.

Comment: it's not enough to include the scripts, the *have* to be at the bottom of your page for the toggle to work.

Comment: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>
this is all I have included it is just a simple, code nothing special

Comment: I have jquery and bootstrap at the bottom and 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"> at the top

Comment: wheres the js script tags? according to your previous comment, you just put style sheets twice on the html

Comment: There are no js files or codes in there I am just trying to see how navbar button works and how it toggles. But after resizing it the button isn't working, there is no reaction.

Comment: If you don't have the `.js` files, it's **NOT** going to work.

Comment: Adding jquery works for me

Comment: **@HaukurHaf** - Please post as answer. It worked great for me. **Thanks!**

Comment: btw the class should be "navbar-toggler" instead of "navbar-toggle"... at least in bootstrap 5

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your code looks great, the only thing i see is that you did not include the collapsed class in your button selector. http://www.bootply.com/cpHugxg2f8
 Note: Requires JavaScript plugin
If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.

The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 3</a>
                    </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It didn't help me.

Answer (score 67):

In Bootstrap 5 data attributes are now namespaced in the js plugin with "bs", so for example **data-toggle** will not work anymore and you will need to use **data-bs-toggle** instead.

Comment: Life saver :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, this was my problem. I switched back from version 5.0 to 4.6 and it started working fine.

Comment: Finally, after 2 days, I am able to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh man, thank you :) This works now for me as well.

Comment: Since Bootstrap 5, this should be shown as the first answer. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me when migrating to BS 5! Too easy to miss...

Comment: This solution worked for me.  This should be included in the Bootstrap tutorial right?

Comment: seriously this is a life saver.. thanks so much!! :D

Answer (score 52):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u1s62Lj8/1/

You need the jQuery and Boostrap Javascript files included in your HTML page for the toggle to work. (Make sure you include jQuery before Bootstrap.)

```
<html>
   <head>
       // stylesheets here
       <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/> 
   </head>
   <body>
      //your html code here

      // js scripts here
      // note jquery tag has to go before boostrap
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posting for a friend. Don't forget to make sure you've not disabled javascript in dev tools the other day like, err, my friend, did. Close dev tools and see if it works! d'oh!

Comment: I had a master page and the reference of jquery libs were included in child pages but not in the master page. Your answered helped me finding the problem, Thank you!

Comment: this didnt work

Answer (score 34):

In Bootstrap 5, change `data-toggle` to `data-bs-toggle` ,
and `data-target` to `data-bs-target`.

Notice that `bs` has been added to the `data` attributes in this release.

Answer (score 9):

Remember load jquery before bootstrap js

Answer (score 3):

Wasted several hours only to realize that viewport meta was missing from my code. Adding here just in case some one else misses it out.

As soon as I added this, the toggle started working fine.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 3):

because u have to have jquery set-up to enable the toggling functionality of the toggler button. So, all u have to do is to add bootstrap.bundle.js before bootstrap.css:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't load twice jquery & bootstrap libraries.

after removing duplicates, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I had added jQuery and bootstrap in the incorrect order in my header files.

****I had to load jQuery BEFORE bootstrap and this solved the issue.****

Answer (score -2):

If you will change the ID then Toggle will not working same problem was with me i just change

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

id="defaultNavbar1" then toggle is working

Comment: He was kinda right... if you change the ID, you'll need to change also `data-target=` in the button. I had removed the ID thinking it was useless...