# Bootstrap navbar collapse toggle button not clicking

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, navbar, bootstrap-4

Why isn't my bootstrap navbar not collapsing? The toggle button shows up but when I click it, nothing happens. (Written in React so using className instead of class.) I even tried copying and pasting directly from the Bootstrap example and it still doesn't work. Am I forgetting to import something somewhere? I also tried copying and pasting from this example from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930160/bootstrap-navbar-toggle-button-not-working) on stackoverflow, didn't work.

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar=in-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a className="navbar-logo page-scroll" href="#about">
                <img src="icon.png" />Page
            </a>
        </div>

        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-in-collapse">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li className="hidden active">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li className="">
                    <a className="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li className="">
                    <a className="page-scroll" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li className="">
                    <a className="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

In my html, it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Kaisin Li</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <script src="./bundle.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: with React you should not be using bootstrap.js because it effects the DOM directly, instead use react-bootstrap or my personal favorite one [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)

Comment: @MorrisS Ah I see, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first, you need to append links to *jQuery* and *bootrstrap.js* to your page. In second, `data-target="#navbar=in-collapse"` should be replaced by `data-target="#navbar-in-collapse"`. See the and run the snippet below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-shrink">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-in-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-logo page-scroll" href="#about">
                <img src="icon.png" />Page
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-in-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden active">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li className="">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#blog">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you use bundles for jQuery and Bootstrap scrips, make shure the scripts are bundled in correct order.

Answer (score 1):

try including bootstrap.min.js too

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load bootstrap js

some functionality in bootstrap depends on it such as navbar collapse

check the fourth point [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#how-it-works)

your code should look something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Kaisin Li</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./bundle.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in you code the data-target="#navbar=in-collapse" has '=' and the id is id="navbar-in-collapse" which does not have '=' it is '-'.check for spelling mistake.

Comment: Accepted answer said the same thing