# how to move navbar to the far right of screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap, I'm still learing css and bootstrap. I would like to move links in ul to the far right of the screen. Please help

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/home">

<img src="../assets/images/My project (1).png" width="40" height="20" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
</a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="mr-auto"></div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li> 
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/property">Property<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>                   
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          
  
        </ul>
  
      </div>
</nav>
```

I tried `justify content:right` but it didnt work. I also tried text-end class but it doesn't work. I also tried to use `justify-content: space-between;` and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply `margin-left: auto` to your `ul` to move them to the right end.

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You may use the following code:

```css
.navbar ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/home">

    <img src="../assets/images/My project (1).png" width="40" height="20" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <div class="mr-auto"></div>
    <ul class="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/property">Property<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope you find this useful! Anything else please let me know in comments.

Comment: It works but when screen size is reduced and I use the toggle button, the links show for a second then are immediately hidden, then it only shows Home link. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @user20843725 Sorry I tried to figure it out but I couldn't find a solution. If you can't find a solution, please ask as a separate question. Someone might help. Also see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930160/bootstrap-navbar-toggle-button-not-working